# How to use Latex in QTextEdit?

Tags: html, qt

When I use notepad, written in Qt, and save typed text, with its formatting, in plain view I have html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="qrichtext" content="1" />
    <style type="text/css">
        p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
    </style>
</head>
<body style=" font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:12pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
    <p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">
        <span style=" color:#5500ff;">Some</span> 
        <span style=" font-size:14pt; font-style:italic;">Text</span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

If we modify the html, the richview in notepad also changes.

I am interested how can we insert latex math language in it?

I am aware of mathjax, but I was not able to make it work in this case.

Comment: you want to enter latex and have it rendered properly? That's way beyond the capabilities of QTextEdit I fear, which is rather basic.

Comment: So Qtextedit can not display math formulas?

Comment: Check [Qt and LaTeXvia KLFBackend](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_and_LaTeX_via_KLFBackend) and [QwtText](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_text.html)

Answer (score 0):

`QTextEdit` does not support any mathematics markup at all. You could of course patch the code to add such support :)